# NSSplitView - Preserve subview width on window resize

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssplitview

I have an `NSSplitView` covering all of my window.

The `NSSplitView` contains two (vertical) subviews, one next to the other.

When the user resizes the window, I want the one on the left to remain intact. How is that doable?

---

P.S. Not the AutoLayout-way.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008202-CH1-SW6

Implement window delegate.

`- windowWillResize:toSize:` in this method save the width of the one on the left

`- windowDidResize:`in this method restore the width of the one on the left